# How to secure docker client connection by default?

Tags: docker, ssl

I'm using https to protect the docker daemon socket. Followed all the steps as mentioned [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/protect-access/#use-tls-https-to-protect-the-docker-daemon-socket). The environment variables are set as below,

- DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
- DOCKER_CERT_PATH=~/.docker  == All my client, ca & server certificates + keys exist here
- DOCKER_HOST=tcp://$HOST:2376

The below command works (when I pass ca, client certificate & key):

```
docker --tlsverify --tlscacert=~/.docker/ca.pem --tlscert=~/.docker/client-cert.pem --tlskey=~/.docker/client-key.pem -H=$HOST:2376 ps
```

According to [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/protect-access/#secure-by-default) , I can secure docker client connections by default and do not need to pass certificates every time but the command "docker ps" , doesn't work for me. It always expects client certificate to be passed.

I also tried executing the below,

```
docker-compose --tlsverify --tlscacert=~/.docker/ca.pem --tlscert=~/.docker/client-cert.pem --tlskey=~/.docker/client-key.pem -H=$HOST:2376  up

ERROR: TLS configuration is invalid - make sure your DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY and DOCKER_CERT_PATH are set correctly
```

How can I secure the docker client connections by default ? I just want to execute like "docker ps" without passing client certificate every time since it already exists in ~/.docker

I have also referred a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38286564/docker-tls-verify-docker-host-and-docker-cert-path-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself ! The client certificate and key generated are having the names as cert.pem and key.pem when I followed the official documentation [instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/protect-access/#use-tls-https-to-protect-the-docker-daemon-socket). I renamed the cert.pem to client-cert.pem and key to client-key.pem in my ~/.docker directory.

Apparently, docker picks the client certificate by default, only if it has name as cert.pem and key.pem. So, my issue here is because of changing the client certificate / key names.